# Loading div showing in android jQuery mobile application

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

While I am doing my first android app with jQuery mobile , I created a simple html page.

While I added the jQuery and jQuery mobile to the page a "loading" showing "div" in the screen ...

I am very new to this . Please help me how to avoid this . My HTML looks like

```
...
</div>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.0rc1.min.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

And the code of "loading div" which present in html page is

```
<div class="ui-loader ui-body-a ui-corner-all"> . . loading script here .... </div>
```

Please help

Comment: Is that all your HTML/scripts?

Comment: What is your question?  Is the "loading script here" message not showing up?

Comment: Why did put the <script> tags within the <body> tags ? Shouldn't it be in the <head> tags ?

Comment: You're using an old version of jQuery Mobile, there have been several revisions and optimizations since 1.0RC1. I highly recommend downloading the latest version: http://www.jquerymobile.com/download